# How can I make a website with dynamic features with wordpress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development

As I am a novice in web development field, I wanted to clarify some questions running in my head.

1. I want to make a multilingual website with dynamic features. Dynamic features can be like anything under the sun. Is it
   possible that I can make a website using WordPress (which is mostly
   considered as blogging platform). Well I know that there are some limitations while making a customized website with wordpress.
2. Should I learn any of the frameworks like Django or rails, if yes
   why (its obvious I would have to learn CSS, Ajax, Javascript, PHP)?
3. Suppose I want to add dynamic features in my wordpress site real
   time features like that of twitter (should I learn ruby on rails
   then?), or building API's, support digg like features ,people submitting
   blogs and reblogging again, aggregaton features, editing features, some
   facebook features like notification features on the top of your profile
   page, colloborative blogging, submitting
   links, photos, videos, social platform for people to know each other and
   follow them, microblogging (realtime) like tumblr. Will it be fully customizable after I get my hands perfectly
   on learning some languages and/or frameworks like rails or django.
4. I don't want to learn drupal as it learning curve is very high and meant for technically good programmers, while I don't have much knowledge of Joomla (and am ready for it to learn if wordpress fails).
5. I also want to make a rich platform for advertisement which will be
   commercial. Is it possible that I make a model of advertisement which is
   in my mind which can link to any other websites, blogs, people (users).

The most interesting,challenging and important question is:

1. If I am not able to make a website with such dynamic features with Wordpress, will I have to make pluggins, widgets,themes on my own which can be fully customized for my website. Is it possible to make such pluggins and themes which can be fulfill above said points.

Comment: Mate, the long horizontal key on your keyboard is the _SpaceBar_, which - as the name says - adds spaces if you press it. Please start using it, so we can read your stuff without having to separate words by ourselfs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes you can

2) No, but spend a lot of time reading up on [**wordpress codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/) (thats more or less your bible) and of course refernce through this site too, full of valuable information.

3) Everything is very easily added to wordpress via plugins, no need to go on steep learning curves

4) Wordpress is probably the most simple of all to learn and very well documented.

5) of course WP is very flexible

6) There are thousand upon thousands of plugins (no need to re-invent the wheel) there is bound to be something that fits your requirements and as well as plugins there are also themes that have been designed specificaly for niche websites

Comment: Its a pleasure Himanshu, if you feel that i have answered your question check it as answered so as to help other users who have a similar thoughts as yourself.

Comment: Sure Mr. Martin.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Martin. WP is simple and very easy to get started with.

The only advice I would add is that you spend some time planning your website and what features you want on it. Research any and every possibility and as Martin pointed out always use the WP Codex as a starting point.

Good Luck